# Finding a non-equilateral triangle whose sides form a geometric sequence and whose angles form an arithmetic sequence

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

This question was on a math competition.

> Is there a triangle, which is not equilateral, whose sides form a geometric sequence and whose angles form an arithmetic sequence?
>
> If such a triangle exists, find its sides and angles.

My attempt:

Assume a triangle with sides $a$, $ar$ and $ar^2$ and its angles $\theta-\phi$ ,$\theta$ and $\theta+\phi$.

Now sum of triangles is always $180°$.
So $\theta = 60°$.

Then using the sine law,
$\dfrac{\sin(\theta-\phi)}a=\dfrac{\sin\theta}{ar}=\dfrac{\sin(\theta+\phi)}{ar^2}$

Cancelling the a and plugging in the equation the value of $\theta$,

$\dfrac{\sin(60°-\phi)}1=\dfrac{\sin60°}{r}=\dfrac{\sin(60°+\phi)}{r^2}$

This is where I am stuck.

Comment: What have you tried? Questions which show little effort tend to do poorly on MSE.

Comment: $r = \frac{\sin 60}{\sin(60 - \phi)} = \frac{\sin(60 + \phi)}{\sin 60}$ might help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following your work, we have

$$r = \frac{\sin\frac{\pi}{3}}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3} - \phi\right)} = \frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3} + \phi\right)}{\sin\frac{\pi}{3}}$$

The last two terms give $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3} - \phi\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3} + \phi\right) = \frac{3}{4}$. We have

$$\begin{align*} LHS &= \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cos\phi - \frac{1}{2}\sin\phi\right)\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cos\phi + \frac{1}{2}\sin\phi\right) \\ &= \frac{3}{4}\cos^2\phi - \frac{1}{4}\sin^2\phi \end{align*}$$

Setting equality, we have

$$\cos^2\phi - \frac{1}{3}\sin^2\phi = 1$$

From this, it is clear that we need $\sin^2\phi = 0$, so there is no non-degenerate triangle satisfying your requirements (assuming your sine law equations are correct :)

Answer (score 2):

Going off of what you have done:
$$\sin(60-\phi) = \sin(60)/r$$
$$\frac{\sin(60)}{\sin(60-\phi)} = r$$
Consider now the second and third expressions:
$$\dfrac{\sin60°}{r}=\dfrac{\sin(60°+\phi)}{r^2}$$
$$r\sin(60)=\sin(60°+\phi)$$
Sub in $r$ from before:
$$\frac{\sin^2(60)}{\sin(60-\phi)}=\sin(60°+\phi)$$
$$\frac 34=\sin(60-\phi)\sin(60°+\phi)$$
Use the trig identity:
$$\sin(a)\sin(b) = \frac{\cos(a-b)-\cos(a+b)}{2}$$
to get:
$$\frac 32=2\sin(60-\phi)\sin(60°+\phi)=cos(2\phi)+1/2$$
$$1=\cos(2\phi)$$
From this it seems $\phi=0$is the only answer.

Comment: There _might_ be something wrong with your last three lines (after "use the trig identity"), since plotting your equation on [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/uxcsxomhsx) shows there is no solution apart from degenerate solution $\phi = k\pi$.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I am on a phone and trying to get lunch at the same time. It is fixed

Comment: Impressive setup haha

Answer (score -1):

If the angles are in arithmetic progression, let them be $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$.
We then have, for some reason $r$, that

$\beta=\alpha+r$ and $\gamma=\alpha+ 2r$.

How
$\alpha+\beta+\gamma=180^\circ \iff \alpha +\alpha+r+\alpha+2r=180^\circ \iff 3\alpha+3r=180^\circ\iff \alpha+r=60 ^\circ$.

Taking $r=2$, for example, we have $\alpha=58^\circ$

As for the sides, you can choose from this that, being these $a,b,c$,

$b=a\times r_2$ and $c=a\times r_2^2$ and
for example,
$b+c\leqslant a$.

Comment: You can't choose the angles and sides separately, they obey the sine rule and cosine rule etc.

Comment: We can find two foundations on these sides and through the laws find out how much the third will have to be.

Comment: Take your example of angles being $(58, 60, 62)$ degrees, can you compute the sides $a, b, c$ that will form a geometric progression? Because the answer I am writing up right now shows that there is no such triangle.

Comment: How does your solution ensure that for all values of $r$ and $a$, the triangle will be valid?