# Please review my proof of triangle existence

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, triangles, arithmetic-progressions

> There is a triangle that is not equilateral whose side lengths form
> a geometric sequence, and the measures of whose angles form an
> arithmetic sequence.
> Show that this statement is true by finding such a triangle or prove that it is false
> by demonstrating that there cannot be such a triangle.

There is already a question on this site regarding this problem but I want someone to review my solution because it is different from the one that already exists on this site. This question came in Euclid Math Contest, $2022$.

---

Let the sides of the triangle be $a,ar,ar^2$ then the angle opposite to $ar^2$ will be $60+d$, angle opposite to $ar$ will be $60$ and angle opposite to $a$ will be $60-d$ where $d,r>0$.

So now by cosine law,
$$(ar)^2=a^2+(ar^2)^2-2(a)(ar^2)\cos60$$
$$\implies r^4-2r^2+1=0$$
$$\implies r=\pm1$$
But $r>0$ and $r\ne1$ $$\boxed{\implies\textrm{No triangle exist}}$$

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't $(a)(a r)$ be $(a)(a r^2)$ in the law of cosines?

Comment: @Gribouillis edited

Comment: Could the angle 60 be opposite to $a$ or $a r^2$ instead of $a r$?

Comment: @Gribouillis i dont think so because the largest angle will be opposite to largest side, second largest angle will be opposite to second largest side and smallest angle will be opposite to smallest side, also $d>0$

Comment: @Gribouillis and also the case $0<r<1$ does not matter because $ar$ will always be second larget no matter what the value of $r$ is

Comment: Where is the other question relative to this problem?

Comment: @Gribouillis https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4438577/finding-a-non-equilateral-triangle-whose-sides-form-a-geometric-sequence-and-who

Comment: Your solution looks correct.